# Auto page break FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

This is the code im using to make a list from data i get out a database. Im using a for each loop to put all data on screen since its a variable amout of data that comes out of the database.

Now im facing the problem that it stops when there are 38 lines of data... I have put SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10); but it does not seem to work.

I kindly aks if someone has a possible solution.

Thanks in forehand :)

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->addPage(); $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16); 
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10); 
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);


// De kop
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0, 0);
$pdf->Text(10, 15, "Balansformulier", TRUE);
$pdf->Text(10, 25, "#", TRUE);
$pdf->Text(30, 25, "Naam", TRUE);
$pdf->Text(100, 25, "Waar", TRUE);
$pdf->Text(154, 25, "Aanwezig?", TRUE);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','i',11);

// horizontale waardes voor de variabelen
$x1=30;
$x2=100;
$x3=160;

// veritcale waardes voor de variabelen
$y=30;
$y2=27;

// waardes voor de nummers
$xnummer=10;
$ynummer=30;
$nummer=0;

//Waardes voor de lijnen
$xlijn=10;
$ylijn=31;



for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){


    foreach($balans_lijst as $balans){

        $nummer++;

        $naam = $html_entities->html_ent($balans['naam']);
        $waar = $html_entities->html_ent($balans['waar']);


        $y = $y+7;
        $y2 = $y2+7;

        $ynummer = $ynummer+7;

        $ylijn = $ylijn+7;



        $pdf->SetXY($x1, $y);


        //Stukken erop zetten
        $pdf->Text($xnummer,$ynummer,"{$nummer}.",1,'L', TRUE);
        $pdf->Text($x1,$y,"{$naam}",1,'L', TRUE);
        $pdf->Text($x2,$y,"{$waar}",1,'L', TRUE);
        $pdf->Line($xlijn, $ylijn, 190, $ylijn);

        $pdf->Rect($x3, $y2, 3, 3);



    }
}
```

Comment: if the default function is not working than have you tried contacting their customer support or any other support of FPDF??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset x y and $pdf->AddPage();

(...)

```
//Stukken erop zetten
                if($nummer % 38 === 0){
                    // horizontale waardes voor de variabelen
                    $x1=30;
                    $x2=100;
                    $x3=160;

                    // veritcale waardes voor de variabelen
                    $y=30;
                    $y2=27;

                    // waardes voor de nummers
                    $xnummer=10;
                    $ynummer=30;

                    //Waardes voor de lijnen
                    $xlijn=10;
                    $ylijn=31;
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                }
$pdf->Text($xnummer,$ynummer,"{$nummer}.",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Text($x1,$y,"{$naam}",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Text($x2,$y,"{$waar}",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Line($xlijn, $ylijn, 190, $ylijn);
```

(...)

Full example

```
$pdf = new \FPDF('P','mm','A4');
        $pdf->addPage(); $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16); 
        $pdf->SetMargins(10, 10); 
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);


        // De kop
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0, 0);
        $pdf->Text(10, 15, "Balansformulier", TRUE);
        $pdf->Text(10, 25, "#", TRUE);
        $pdf->Text(30, 25, "Naam", TRUE);
        $pdf->Text(100, 25, "Waar", TRUE);
        $pdf->Text(154, 25, "Aanwezig?", TRUE);


        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','i',11);

        // horizontale waardes voor de variabelen
        $x1=30;
        $x2=100;
        $x3=160;

        // veritcale waardes voor de variabelen
        $y=30;
        $y2=27;

        // waardes voor de nummers
        $xnummer=10;
        $ynummer=30;
        $nummer=0;

        //Waardes voor de lijnen
        $xlijn=10;
        $ylijn=31;

        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){


            for($i=0; $i<500; $i++){

                $nummer++;

                $naam = 'XXXXXX';
                $waar = 'XXXXXXXXXX';


                $y = $y+7;
                $y2 = $y2+7;

                $ynummer = $ynummer+7;

                $ylijn = $ylijn+7;



                $pdf->SetXY($x1, $y);


                //Stukken erop zetten
                if($nummer % 38 === 0){
                    // horizontale waardes voor de variabelen
                    $x1=30;
                    $x2=100;
                    $x3=160;

                    // veritcale waardes voor de variabelen
                    $y=30;
                    $y2=27;

                    // waardes voor de nummers
                    $xnummer=10;
                    $ynummer=30;

                    //Waardes voor de lijnen
                    $xlijn=10;
                    $ylijn=31;
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                }
                $pdf->Text($xnummer,$ynummer,"{$nummer}.",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Text($x1,$y,"{$naam}",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Text($x2,$y,"{$waar}",1,'L', TRUE);
                $pdf->Line($xlijn, $ylijn, 190, $ylijn);

                $pdf->Rect($x3, $y2, 3, 3);



            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It made a difference for me when I added it directly after creating the new object,

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);
```